# Module fails to import when installing from github repo as egg in pip

Tags: python, git, import, egg

I have created a [repo](https://github.com/vulcan25/plugable-api/tree/9c08ae74fe8d9c4b3207126f0be47ae4fe93ce81) based on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/theorm/5440144) in order to use the functionality in my own applications.

I added a [setup.py](https://github.com/vulcan25/plugable-api/blob/9c08ae74fe8d9c4b3207126f0be47ae4fe93ce81/setup.py). Then installed with:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/vulcan25/plugable-api#egg=plugable-api
```

The gist has some boilerplate in `__init__.py` which I will ultimately put elsewhere in my application:

```
from .base import the_api
```

...so I deleted this file, then renamed `base.py` to `__init__.py` hoping that this would allow me to to do the following in my application.

```
from plugable_api import the_api
```

This gave an import error, so I tried renaming this file again to `plugable-api.py` based on the fact that `setup.py` contains: `modules=['plugable_api'],` but still I get the same import error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plugable_api'
```

Can someone tell me what I've missed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh, knew it would be something obvious.

> renaming this file again to `plugable-api.py`

Should have had the underscore, not hypen:  `plugable_api.py`